# Ajax Registration FOSUserBundle

Tags: ajax, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I am trying to register a user via AJAX using FOSUserBundle.

The problem is that the name value in the form is `fos_user_registration_form_[username]` so it isn't accepted by javascript as array.

```
<input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" />
```

How can I solve that?

Can I change the name parameter in FOSUserBUndle to `fos_user_registration_form_username` ?

How can I create an array with `fos_user_registration_form_[username]` value in Javascript?

```
$("#registerButton").click( function(){

             data = {
                 fos_user_registration_form_[username]:$("#name").val(), // HERE IS WHERE IT CRASHES, IN THE [username] field.
                 fos_user_registration_form_[email]:$("#email").val(),
                 fos_user_registration_form_[plainPassword]:$("#password").val(),
             };

             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: serviceURL,
                    asyn:false,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(res) {

                        alert("success"); // JUST FOR TEST

                    }
              });
```

I am testing a basic example..

This works (triggers the alert)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        data = {
            fos_user_registration_form_username:"blabla"
        };
        alert(true);
</script>
```

This doesn't works: (do not trigger the alert)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        data = {
            fos_user_registration_form_[username]:"blabla"
        };
        alert(true);
</script>
```

Comment: This is not `fos_user_registration_form_[username]` but `fos_user_registration_form[username]`.

And use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to extract the form values, it handle everything.

Comment: What do you mean? Serialize de data array?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the data from your input fields, you need to combine the `name_of_the_form_` + the `name_of_the_field`. For example:

`fos_user_registration_form_` + `username`  => `fos_user_registration_form_username`

---

```
data = {
fos_user_registration_form[username]:$("#fos_user_registration_form_username").val(), 
fos_user_registration_form[email]:$("#fos_user_registration_form_email").val(),
fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]:$("#fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword").val(),
};
```

Comment: Maybe I have explained myself bad.. I am not using a form, I just want to send the values. I have fos_user_registration_form_[username]:"myusername",  and I want the fosuserBundle controler to recieve and validate those values.. so to validate I supose it is expecting to recieve a fos_user_registration_form_[username] as a post parameter..

Comment: Thank you for your help Patt.. I am developing a mobile application (in phonegap) which users can register via ajax to a symfony2 app. So I used what you said to get the username, email, etc... so next step is send them to the controler which is FOSUSerBudnle default controler. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php

Comment: The problem is that in $form->isValid() return false because I am not passing the mandatory parameters like fos_user_registration_form_[username].. so what I want is to modify the Bundle to set username instead od [username] <input type="text" name="fos_user_registration_form_username"/>